# Why are these stacking on top of eachother Bootstrap Span

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

My two column layout is stacking on top of each other instead of sitting side by side.

Can anyone help me out?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span8">
                    <img src="img/banner-cat.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span4">
                    <form class="form">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" First Name">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" Last Name">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using Bootstrap 2. Read the docs and look at the order of the css files and how to use the grid. getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/ -- there are examples of the fluid grid.

Comment: Are your libraries Bootstrap version 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of unnecessary divs:

```
<body>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8">
            <img src="img/banner-cat.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <form class="form">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" First Name">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" Last Name">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Basically, anything that should be in a row needs to be within the same `row` or `row-fluid` container. This is covered in the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem